# Can iCloud notes be synced with different accounts?

Tags: mac, data-synchronization, icloud, accounts, notes.app

Is it possible to synchronize notes with different accounts? For example, if I write something in my notes - my friend will open his notes with his account and see the change.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, iCloud was not meant to work that way.

Some *third party* Apps, though, will do exactly what you're looking for. [AppCrawlr](http://appcrawlr.com/ios-apps/best-apps-shared-notes) has got an interesting list, which might be worth looking at.

Comment: Just that this domain doesn't exist anymore....

Comment: @sorin Fixed! Changed to a more useful one. :)